# Prove that if $n^6$ is a perfect square, $n^{50}$ is a perfect square.

Tags: proof-writing

Can someone help me prove/disprove this?

I wrote $n^6$ as $l^2$, but I don't know how to convert $n^{50}$ into that format because $^{50}$ is too large.

$n$ ∈ ℤ

Comment: What kind of number is $n$?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that, $n$ ∈ ℤ

Comment: Typesetting note, just use `{ }` in order to have longer exponents.  `n^{reallylong}` gives $n^{reallylong}$ as opposed to `n^reallylong` which gives $n^reallylong$

Comment: But $n^6=(n^3)^2$ is *always* a perfect square...

Comment: About the question, if $n$ is indeed an integer, then it doesn't matter that $n^6$ is a perfect square since $n^{50}$ is always going to be a perfect square anyways.  The more interesting question is if $n$ is not necessarily an integer but it turns out that $n^6$ is a perfect square, for example $n=\sqrt[3]{2}$.  In this case, what happens?  $(\sqrt[3]{2})^6=4$ and $(\sqrt[3]{2})^{50}=?$

Comment: @JMoravitz: One could make it fancier by asking, given that $x^{50}$ is an integer, whether it is a perfect square.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hmm, interesting.  Mightn't that make it obviously true when $n$ is an integer and vacuously true when $n$ is not?  $n^6$ being a perfect square implies that $n=p_1^{\frac{\alpha_1}{3}}p_2^{\frac{\alpha_2}{3}}\dots$ and is an integer if and only if $3\mid \alpha_i$ for each $i$.  When $n$ is not an integer, that means that there is some $\alpha_i$ that is not a multiple of three, which after multiplication by $50$ will again not be a multiple of $3$, implying that $n^{50}$ would not be an integer.

Comment: Sure, the point is one has to work. Reflex action on my part, trying to make up a "new" test/homework question.

Answer (score 2):

Both $n^6$ and $n^{50}$ are perfect squares, since $n^6=(n^3)^2$ and $n^{50}=(n^{25})^2$. What's the problem?